# MVC Object Change Tracking

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I've currently got an issue where I need to see which fields have been changed on an Edit field for auditing purposes, in which I have code for, but I think my problem lies within my MVC View.

I have (test code):

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Adjustment(GroupPolicy groupPolicy)
{
          if (ModelState.IsValid)
          {
              _service.SaveGroupPolicy(groupPolicy);
              return RedirectToAction("Index");
          }
          return View(groupPolicy);
}
```

Which is fine, the Policy saves. However, take this into consideration:

GroupPolicy has, say, 3 fields (in reality there are, maybe, 60):

```
bool IsPolicy
string Name
string Description
```

Name and Description are on the form, so that's fine. IsPolicy isn't used on the form, so that gets **defaulted to false** when posted back to the GroupPolicy object in the Adjustment method.

I can't really put `IsPolicy` in a Hidden field on the form, as that won't be elegant for 60+ fields in my actual solution, the HTML would be all over the place.

Now that the bool is defaulted to false, it completely abolishes the chance of me knowing if the field has changed or not. All I really want is a method for this data to be preserved, whilst keeping the new information on the Edit form.

Is this possible, am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Why do you need all those properties if they aren't in the form anyway? If they aren't in the edit form then they "couldn't" be changed anyway. Or am _I_ missing something here?

Comment: Because I'm trying to make my entire auditing generic, so looking at properties CurrentValues / OldValues in Entity Framework and differentiating between them. However, this can't be possible with my scenario due to the OldValues all being defaulted.

Comment: @thedixon what you are doing above is not the best practice.  You are blindly accepting a GroupPolicy from the client and saving it.  What if a user uses firebug and changes all the properties that are supposed to be read only and posts it?

Comment: I think the answer below should get around that, by using a ViewModel, rather than the Entity itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well first of all, `GroupPolicy` should be a *view* model and not an entity - and as such it should be tailored for the view e.g.

```
public class GroupPolicyViewModel
{
    [HiddenInput]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Then in your action you don't need to worry about assigning values that have changed, you just map the view model directly across e.g.

```
public ActionList Adjustment(GroupPolicyViewModel viewModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // pull actual entity from service
        var groupPolicy = _service.GetGroupPolicy(viewModel.Id);
        // update entity from view model
        groupPolicy.Name = viewModel.Name;
        groupPolicy.Description = viewModel.Description;
        ...
    }
}
```

This keeps a clean separation between your view & business logic. Also, it allows you to add annotations for client-side validation without affecting your *real* model.

> GroupPolicy has, say, 3 fields (in reality there are, maybe, 60)

I would recommend using [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) for this e.g.

```
// call this once only e.g. Application_Start in the Global.asax
Mapper.CreateMap<GroupPolicyViewModel, GroupPolicy>();
...
// in your Adjustment action
var groupPolicy = _service.GetGroupPolicy(viewModel.Id);
groupPolicy = Mapper.Map<GroupPolicyViewModel, GroupPolicy>(viewModel, groupPolicy);
_service.SaveGroupPolicy(groupPolicy);
```

Comment: I *think* this is what I'm needing, it looks promising, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

If `IsPolicy` not on the form then it shouldn't even be part of your model - this will prevent posting of this field into your model and so your check won't even be needed for IsPolicy.

Rather than accepting `GroupPolicy` as the parameter into the action, create a cut down object `GroupPolicyInputModel` with only fields that are on the form.

Then use your generic auditing to only compare all the posted fields, as per any other form.